# How do I get my Github repository to reflect a merge on my machine?

Tags: git, github

After successfully merging a branch with my master branch, when I checkout my master branch, it says I’m ahead by 4 commits. The commits are from the merged branch.

In other words, the master branch on my github repository isn’t reflecting the merge I made on my local machine.

I’m pretty sure I can correct this with a push, but I’m also given to understand that pushing to the master is bad form. Is this an exception to the rule since I made a branch first? Is there a way I can merge more cleanly in the future?

Edit: To be clear, I used the command ‘git merge’ locally.

Comment: Are you the only contributor to the repo? If so you can do whatever you like.

Comment: (replaced with different question after re-reading the question) I gather you ran `git merge` locally rather than using, e.g., the GitHub web interface with its green `merge`/`rebase-and-merge`/`squash-and-merge` buttons. This is OK, but yes, you will then need to `git push`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't push to the `master` branch because you complete pull requests on GitHub (or BitBucket or another git hosting site) and the site does the merge for you.  But if you do a merge locally as you have done, then you will have to `push` to the `master` branch to see your change reflected on the remote.

If you are the only contributor to the repo, or you have a small team and they are okay with it, then there is no problem with doing so.

You will just run

```
git push origin master
```

In the future, if you want to avoid merging locally and then pushing, you can create a pull request for others to review on GitHub (or your hosting site of choice), and then once the review is complete you can use the site to merge the PR.  If you are the only contributor though, there is nothing wrong with pushing to the `master` branch, and in fact it would be silly to make a PR for only yourself to review.

Comment: I’m the only contributor, so your answer meets my needs. Out of curiosity, how would the answer change if I was on a larger team?

Comment: @cssstyleless, on a larger team I would say that only a git expert should be pushing to `master`, and even then only to fix specific issues that come up, because it has the potential to lose other people's work.  The standard approach on a team of any size is to do all your merges into `master` by completing pull requests.  This ensures that everyone is able to review all the code that gets into the "official" branch.